# ASP.NET 2.0 Application on IIS 5 Resulting in Error (aspnet_wp.exe (PID: XXXX) stopped unexpectedly.)

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-2.0, asp.net-2.0, iis-5

After hosting an ASP.NET 2.0 web application on a windows 2000 server(IIS 5).
I was unable to browse the web site.

The following error message was displayed on the browser and three Event Log entries were added...

**Error Message on Browser**

> Server Application Unavailable The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable.  Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web browser to retry your request.

**Event Log Entries**

> Event Type:   Error
>   Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
>   Event Category: None
>   Event ID:   1000
>   Date:       10/24/2008
>   Time:       3:45:26 PM
>   User:       N/A
>   Computer:   XXXXX
>   Description:    aspnet_wp.exe  (PID: XXXX) stopped unexpectedly.
>
> Event Type:   Error
>   Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
>   Event Category: None
>   Event ID:   1088
>   Date:       10/24/2008
>   Time:       3:45:26 PM
>   User:       N/A
>   Computer:   XXXXX
>   Description:    Failed to execute request because the App-Domain could not be created. Error: 0x80070005 Access is denied.
>
> Event Type:   Warning
>   Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
>   Event Category: None
>   Event ID:   1073
>   Date:       10/24/2008
>   Time:       3:45:26 PM
>   User:       N/A
>   Computer:   WEBDEV
>   Description:    Failed to initialize the AppDomain:/LM/W3SVC/1/Root/WebApplicationName
>   Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException
>   Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.
>   StackTrace:    at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
>      at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
>      at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)

Any Ideas...

** Edit **

And Why System.IO.FileLoadException is thrown for accessing System.Web assembly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that when the web site folder was copied to the server it inherited the security permissions of the parent folder which only had permission for the Administrator, Administrators & System accounts.

I added

- IUSER_MACHINENAME (Internet Guest Account)
- ASPNET (ASP.NET Machine Account)

With **Read & Execute**, **List Folder Contents** and **Read** permissions.

**Even though the problem is resolved I still have some questions**

It's clear from the third event log entry that the ApplicationManager fails to create the HostingEnvironment  which is in the System.Web assembly.
Since FileLoadException is thrown for System.Web it seems like the ASP.NET worker process doesn't have access to the GAC folder.

Why is the FileLoadException thrown for accessing System.Web?

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you have an incorrect permission set for your ASP.NET installation.  Typically the best bet it to just uninstall and re-install the ASP.NET portion.  You can do this easily by the following.

1. Open command prompt to C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727
2. run the following command: aspnet_regiis.exe -u
3. run the following command: aspnet_regiis.exe -i

That will uninstall ASP.NET and re-install, that should then establish the proper permissions for the account.

Comment: Much easier than hacking the permissions:-)

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your code has thrown an exception that has either crashed IIS, or forced it to shut down. Common exceptions that cause this are OutOfMemoryException and StackOverflowException.

You're getting a FileLoadException, but there could be an underlying OutOfMemoryException or similar that's actually the root cause of that. Without knowing what you're trying to load, and the code that's inside it, it's impossible to tell what's actually causing your problem.

The first thing I would do to rule out a problem with the loading assembly, though, is to try and reflect over it in a test harness and see if the same problem happens. If so, then the problem is with the DLL that you're trying to load, not IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it didn't go away with aspnet_regiis with -u and -i and many others suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/bf530e90-5d42-4909-a858-6be0ae28717d).
But after I cleaned “%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files” folder and gave this folder read-write permissions to user from identity impersonate section in web.config, problem disappeared. It was not sufficient to give local ASPNET user those rights.