# basic iis 5.0 xml parsing error on local site

Tags: asp.net, iis, isapi

I'm starting a new job and am inheriting a asp .net web application on the 2.0 .net framework. The application works alright. It published successfully from vs 2005. I created a new virtual directory in IIS and pointed to the precompiled directory just published.

When I load my application, I get an error that reads as follows:

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost/Subpoena/
Line Number 1, Column 2:<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="Home, App_Web_ysxqzhr9" %>
-^

I'm not real sure what to do to fix this. The App_Web_ysxqzhr9 is a dll in the bin directory that was created by VS 2005 when I published the project.

I admit I'm a bit rusty on my IIS skills so it might be some setting that I haven't set...or it could be something entirely different.

Anyone have any thoughts at all?

Answer (score 1):

*sigh*

Okay found the answer. Ironically it too was on stack overflow. Here it is:

[ASP.NET 2.0 Application on IIS 5 Resulting in Error (aspnet_wp.exe (PID: XXXX) stopped unexpectedly.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233478/aspnet-20-application-on-iis-5-resulting-in-error-aspnetwpexe-pid-xxxx-stopped)

What worked for me was Mitchel Sellers response:

1. Open command prompt to C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727
2. run the following command: aspnet_regiis.exe -u
3. run the following command: aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Thanks anyway for all your help guys.

Comment: you can actually have the same effect by runing aspnet_regiis.exe -iru i've had that same problem in the past but it looks like it manifested differently for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is your IIS configured correctly? You should double check that the asp file is actually being interpreted as ASP and not just trying to be displayed as XML by the browser. In the configuration for the folder and make sure the button next to the Application Name field says Remove not Create.

Answer (score -1):

You may also need to install Microsoft WSE extensions.

Something like this: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=018a09fd-3a74-43c5-8ec1-8d789091255d&displaylang=en

EDIT:
System.Web is part of the WSE but I'm not sure how it all plays together.

Comment: System.Web is a normal part of .NET. It includes ASP.NET and ASMX web services. WSE should be avoided at all costs. -1, and I'd downvote multiple times if I could.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting he use WSE in general. It seems possible that the app he inherited may have used it and consequently might need to have it installed for his development.